# PHP: How to use class method as anonymous function with parameters

Tags: php, anonymous

I have got sample code as above

```
add_hook('AdminAreaHeadOutput', 1, function($vars) {
   return "some String";
})
```

Source of code: https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/output/#adminareaheadoutput

It is possible to call class method instead anonymous function ?

Something like that :

```
$myClass = new myclass();
add_hook('AdminAreaHeadOutput', 1, $myClass->AdminAreaHeadOutput($vars));
```

It is possible to pass anonymous function args to class method ?

Comment: Do you pass the variables immediately or the callback passes them to the function itself?

Answer (score 1):

Yest it is possible ;)

```
add_hook('AdminAreaHeadOutput', 1, function($vars){

$myClass = new MyClass();
return $myClass->AdminAreaHeadOutput($vars);

});
```